# Angular lazy loading routing with loadchildren

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have an ionic app that has tabs and a login page. The tabs component is its own module and has a routing module for each tab and each tab is its own module. When the app loads I want to direct to the login page, then upon logging in redirect to one of the tabs tabs(menu/home) off the tabs component.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => 
    m.TabsPageModule)
  }, 
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: "",
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'menu',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'library',
        loadChildren: () => import('./library/library.module').then(m => m.LibraryPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'search',
        loadChildren: () => import('./search/search.module').then(m => m.SearchPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        loadChildren: () => import('./profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfileModule)
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'menu/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/menu/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I am having an error when trying to navigate to "menu/home" from the login component. Route is not found. @AakashGarg

Comment: Find my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Change your tabs routing to :-

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'menu',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: TabsPage
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'library',
        loadChildren: () => import('./library/library.module').then(m => m.LibraryPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'search',
        loadChildren: () => import('./search/search.module').then(m => m.SearchPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        loadChildren: () => import('./profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfileModule)
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'menu/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/menu/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

**OR**

Put a router-outlet in TabsPage

To understand the reason read :- https://link.medium.com/U5u4d4ub66